# Странный оператор =>?

Tags: perl

Всем известно, что оператор `=>` рассматривает левый оператор как строку.

Однако, случайно наткнулся на такое (в жизни такой код врядли встретиться):

```
perl -wle 'use constant X => 1; print (2 + X => 3);'
Argument «X» isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
23

perl -wle 'use constant X => 1; print (X + 2 => 3);'
33
```

То есть в одном случае в выражении «2 + X», константа X, не раскрылась, однако сложение всё-таки выполнилось, а в другом случае, в выражении «X + 2», константа X раскрылась.

Что это может быть?

Вот что пишет документация (perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator):

> The => operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a
>   word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a
>   letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and
>   underscores.

То есть если левая часть начинается с буквы, подчеркивания и состоит только из букв, цифр и подчеркиваний, она интерпретируется как строка.

Здесь есть знак "+", значит, оба выражения уже не могут рассматриваться как строка, они оба и выполняются, однако, только в одном случае раскрывается константа X, **почему так**? Приоритеты? Или что?

Comment: perldoc perlop на тему оператора =>

Comment: Спасибо за совет, уже читал, там мало написано.

Answer (score 1):

Приоритеты. X - функция.

Comment: Я знаю, что константы это, на самом деле, функции
Почему тогда функция выполняется в случае "X + 2", но не выполняется в другом - "2 + X" ?

Comment: `# perl -wle 'use constant X => 1; print (2 + X() => 3);'`
33

Comment: И что?
perl -wle 'use constant X => 1; print (X() + 2 => 3);'
33

Мне надо ответить, почему здесь не раскрывается
perl -wle 'use constant X => 1; print (2 + X => 3);

Comment: > Почему тогда функция выполняется в случае "X + 2", но не выполняется в другом - "2 + X"

Потому что X, за которым следует "толстая запятая" (=>), превращается в строку. Подобный пример рассмотрен в perlop - сразу за процитированным в вопросе высказыванием.

Comment: то, что "=>" интерпретирует левый операнд как строку, я это знаю и написал первым предложением. Однако, если у "=>" приоритет над "+", то он какой-то странный приоритет, "недоприоритет", я бы сказал.

Имхо, тогда 2 + X => 3 должно быть эквивалентно 2 + (X => 3), но это не так (такой вариант должен давать 5, проверьте)

Если же у плюса приоритет над =>
тогда и "2 + X => 3", и "X + 2 => 3" должно быть эквивалентно (2 + X) => 3 и давать одинаковые результаты.

То есть, если у "=>" приоритет над "+", то это, как-будто, какой-то недоприоритет.

Comment: Приоритет, недоприоритет... Это -- perl. Что там на самом деле решали разработчики (Larry Wall или кто-то ещё) -- я не знаю. Но какую-то логику найти можно. use constant действует во время компиляции и анализ операнда => должен происходить тогда же. Очевидно, что это несколько раньше, чем анализируются приоритеты (а приоритет у него как у запятой). И разработчики отделили котлеты приоритетов от мух подстановки констант.

А вообще нормальному человеку от этого языка лучше держаться подальше

Comment: Понятно, оператор "=>", мол, обрабатывается на стадии компиляции, а приоритеты -- на стадии выполнения, отсюда и такие "чудеса".

Зачем подальше? Не стоит уж так бояться.

Comment: @Олег2 нет, разумеется всё обрабатывается на стадиях компиляции, просто на разных стадиях. А насчёт перла, так была в советское время детская песенка: "Раз дощечка, два дощечка -- будет лесенка, раз словечко, два словечко -- будет песенка". И перл создавался примерно таким макаром...

Comment: > ...Однако, если у "=>" приоритет над "+"...

Нет, у оператора "=>" (запятая) приоритет ниже, чем у "+". См. ответ @dionys - он всё хорошо объяснил.

Answer (score 1):

```
> perl -MO=Deparse -E 'use constant X => 1; say(2 + X => 3)'
use constant ('X', 1);
say 2 + 'X', 3;
```

Всё просто, нельзя использовать константы, объявленные через прагму `constant`, в качестве ключей при операторе `=>`. Интерпретатор считает их bareword и превращает в строку.

И приоритет в этом случае никак не нарушается, замена на строку (как и прочие оптимизации выражений) происходит на этапе компиляции, а не выполнения. А при выполнении вычисление происходит в полном соответствии с таблицей приоритетов.

Обходится это так:

```
> perl -MO=Deparse -E 'use constant X => 1; say(2 + (X) => 3)'
use constant ('X', 1);
say 3, 3;
```

Comment: Это обходится ещё и так:
2 + &X
2 + X()

Так как на самом деле "use constant" создаёт функцию.
Просто прикол в том, что в этом случае
X + 2 => константа X раскрывается сама по себе

Comment: @Олег2, мне эти два способа не кажутся красивыми.